# How to migrate Db using EF in code instead of Nuget package manager console?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to make a test method in Unit tests which will apply migrations on the DB. So I have googled for a while and found information about the `DbMigrator` class. Here is the example usage for EF 4.3:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

This one didn't work, because I'm using EF 5.0. So I made something like this:

```
DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("***", "System.Data.SqlClient");
configuration.ContextType = typeof (EfContext);
//Dies here
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

But it throws the exception - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
Here is stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationAssembly..ctor(Assembly migrationsAssembly, String migrationsNamespace)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
at CloudAdNet.Testing.UnitTests.Test.SeedTest() in c:\Users\maris.vigulis\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CloudAdNetSoftware\CloudAdNet.Testing.UnitTests\Test.cs:line 19
```

Any advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make your `Configuration` as a public class:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContextClassHere>
```

2) Add anywhere the code below, this will run the latest migration and updates your db:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.ContextType = typeof(YourContextClassHere);
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

//This will get the SQL script which will update the DB and will write it to debug
var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
string script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null).ToString();
Debug.Write(script);

//This will run the migration update script and will run Seed() method
migrator.Update();
```